# How to ensure that the selected node's sub-treeview is visible?

Tags: c#, treeview

I have an expanded treeview. If I'm typing the first characters to quickly access a certain node, the selected node is displayed at the bottom of treeview's frame, but its own sub-treeview isn't visible. How to ensure that the selected node's whole sub-treeview is visible?

Now:

```
|_a
|_[b]
=============treeview's frame bottom margin
```

Expected result:

```
|_a
|_[b]
  |_1
  |_2
  | |_k
  |_3
=============
```

Comment: [EnsureVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ExpandAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.expandall%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I already used ExpandAll when I displayed the whole treeview. But how to use EnsureVisible to the selected node's children?

Comment: Try: `yourTreeView.SelectedNode.Expand()` in the `yourTreeView_AfterSelect` Or simply press the right cursor key. There is also a `node.LastNode` method..

Answer (score 0):

This should alwys keep the last child of the selected node in view:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Expand();
    treeView1.SelectedNode.LastNode.EnsureVisible();
}
```

To find the last child of the last child etc you can write a **recursive** `LastChildNode` function:

```
TreeNode LastChildNode(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0) return LastChildNode(node.LastNode);
    else return node;
}
```

To use it you could change the `AfterSelect` code to:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode lastChild = LastChildNode(treeView1.SelectedNode.LastNode);
    if (lastChild != null) lastChild.EnsureVisible();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm a beginner, how to exactly use that LastChildNode function in order to ensure the last child node is visible?

Comment: Unfortunately the program crashes. Here's the error: http://pastebin.com/aVnJabbK

Comment: Well you need to add one or more checks. Please use the debugger to find out which object is null. Could be Selectednode (when nothing is selected) cold be LastNode (if the are no child nodes), could be lastChild (if the function fails)..

Comment: Whoops there was a mistake in the function. Corrected

Comment: I copied that updated code but it still crashes. The code should get the last child on the selected node and ensure it's visible.

Comment: Why and where does it crash? There is no way to get around using the debugger for these problems! I don't have your data and don't know your actions. Call interrupt when it crashes and look into what is null and where it came from!

Comment: OK. I'm going to make a little test program for these functions.

Comment: I did that test program. I found where's the problem. Instead **TreeNode lastChild = LastChildNode(treeView1.SelectedNode.LastNode);** it should be **TreeNode lastChild = LastChildNode(treeView1.SelectedNode);**.